# ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received

Tags: python-3.x, text, tf-idf, countvectorizer

Trying to identify the weight value of a using `TFIDF` and `count vectorizer`

Below code works fine when I execute that individually for each row. It throws an error adding a loop or using a function.

```
function and tried using a lambda function 
def t_keywo(text):
    tf_idf_vector=tfidf_transformer.transform(cv.transform(text))
    #sort the tf-idf vectors by descending order of scores
    sorted_items=sort_coo(tf_idf_vector.tocoo())
    keywords=extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names,sorted_items)

    return keywords

for loop 

for i in range(len(df_cs_l)):
    tf_idf_vector=tfidf_transformer.transform(cv.transform(df_cs_l[i]))
    #sort the tf-idf vectors by descending order of scores
    sorted_items=sort_coo(tf_idf_vector.tocoo())
    keywords=extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names,sorted_items)
    ref={'Text':i,'words': keywords}
    rel.append(ref)
```

when I executed the above code it throws me below error

`Error: "ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received."`

have seen the same error in below link

[clicl here to view the example](https://discuss.datasciencedojo.com/t/error-iterable-over-raw-text-documents-expected-string-object-received-tfidf-vectorizer/614)

Comment: Please, edit your question with the right indentation.

Answer (score 1):

have made changes in function and works.

```
def t_keywo(text,cv,tfidf_transformer,tf_idf_vector):
    tf_idf_vector=tfidf_transformer.transform(cv.transform([text]))
    #sort the tf-idf vectors by descending order of scores
    sorted_items=sort_coo(tf_idf_vector.tocoo())
    keywords=extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names,sorted_items)

    return keywords

df_cs['keywords'] = df_cs['text'].apply(lambda x:t_keywo(x,cv,tfidf_transformer,tf_idf_vector))
```